# How do I can get list of Google YouTube API methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get list of YouTube API (v3) methods, because I want to implement a simple client library, which will not contain URL to every method, and just call them with their name.
I'll use Python for this.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything more definitive than https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sous2817 said, you can see all the methods that the YouTube API supports in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

> This reference guide explains how to use the API to perform all of these operations. The guide is organized by resource type. A resource represents a type of item that comprises part of the YouTube experience, such as a video, a playlist, or a subscription. For each resource type, the guide lists one or more data representations, and resources are represented as JSON objects. The guide also lists one or more supported methods (`LIST`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc.) for each resource type and explains how to use those methods in your application.

Here are [Python Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python) which use the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/):

> **Call the API's captions.list method to list the existing caption tracks.**

```
def list_captions(youtube, video_id):
  results = youtube.captions().list(
    part="snippet",
    videoId=video_id
  ).execute()

  for item in results["items"]:
    id = item["id"]
    name = item["snippet"]["name"]
    language = item["snippet"]["language"]
    print "Caption track '%s(%s)' in '%s' language." % (name, id, language)

  return results["items"]
```

> **Call the API's captions.download method to download an existing caption track.**

```
def download_caption(youtube, caption_id, tfmt):
  subtitle = youtube.captions().download(
    id=caption_id,
    tfmt=tfmt
  ).execute()

  print "First line of caption track: %s" % (subtitle)
```

[More sample codes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#create_and_manage_youtube_video_caption_tracks).